# ClusterFuture with snow blocks

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, snow

I'm trying to get a long running, embarrassing parallel analysis using snow and future to run asynchronously. But, the ClusterFuture is blocking, simplified code below. Is there a way to keep ClusterFuture from blocking? Or am I just doing something wrong? Running R version 3.5.3 on 64 bit Windows (and eventually on Linux as well).

thanks
Mark

tried just lapply with snow, and just future. ClusterFuture with parLapply works really nicely, execution time exactly what it should be (8 times as fast). But, it blocks and I'd really like it to behave like a regular future (and return control to the console).

```
rm(list=ls())
RunNM2 <- function(index){
  Sys.sleep(4)
  return(index)
}
library(tictoc)
library(future)
library(snow)
cl <- future::makeClusterPSOCK(rep("localhost",8),makeNode =         
 makeNodePSOCK)
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
tic("cluster")
res.1 <- ClusterFuture(parLapply(cl,1:8,RunNM2),worker=cl )
##blocks here
res <- value(res.1)
toc()
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the actual parallel workload is not handled by `future` but by `snow::parLapply`. You can see that with the following example, where I am using `parallel` instead of `snow`, which I would treat as deprecated for simple PSOCK clusters:

```r
RunNM2 <- function(index){
    Sys.sleep(4)
    return(index)
}
library(tictoc)
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(rep("localhost",8))
tic("cluster")
res <- parLapply(cl,1:8,RunNM2)
toc()
#> cluster: 4.015 sec elapsed
stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So currently you are creating *one* future out of the result of your parallel computation. Instead you should create several futures, that are then evaluated in parallel:

```r
RunNM2 <- function(index){
    Sys.sleep(4)
    return(index)
}
library(tictoc)
library(future)
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(rep("localhost",8))
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
tic("cluster")
res.1 <- lapply(1:8, function(index) future(RunNM2(index)))
res <- values(res.1)
# blocks here
toc()
#> cluster: 4.66 sec elapsed
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
rm(cl)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note: As per `?cluster` the prefered method for creating a `ClusterFuture` is `future()` or `%<-%` after registering a suitable (cluster) plan for execution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I spent several days trying to figure this out, thanks

Comment: Ralf, thanks again for your very helpful answer on my previous question, I've posted a new one about nested futures with cluster, any help would be appreciated.